# Android : layout_weight seems to work in design but doesn't work in app

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Here is xml code. Layout looks good in design but in app, all three views wraps up to left.
This layout is for custom Array adapter for `ListView` . Target sdk version is 29.

Edit : [Required Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxPv1.png)
Edit 2 : [image: Getting this on run]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text=" textView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBalance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="5000"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have any screen shot/outline of required layout

Answer (score 2):

You are using weight wrong , you don't weight for all the 3 views . weight only for 1st textview and remaining views wrap content . also the parent has some margins

try this layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text=" textView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBalance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="5000"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are you getting after this code , can you add screen shot ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. Took the liberty of making your button circular.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=" textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewBalance"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="5000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButtonPlus"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlus"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_ripple_effect">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:tint="@color/grey_8080"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24"
            android:contentDescription="Profile"/>
    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

@drawable/circular_button_ripple_effect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```